# Youtube API "An error occurred while initializing the YouTube player."

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using Youtube API to have simple playerView on my application. I did what the API said to do but I keep getting "application is stopped" message. I don't really know the exact english phrase since I'm using a Korean Phone. Hope that's the right phrase in English.

I put Youtubeandroidplayerapi.jar in libs and built the path and have the unnecessary components in library.

Here is Menu.java.

```
package com.hobak.sci;

import com.hobak.sci.DeveloperKey;
import com.hobak.sci.R;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Menu extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);

        YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    youTubeView.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
        YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.cueVideo("2LHv1FPd1Ec");
    }
}

protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,
        YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

and here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFACD"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


  <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />



</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my logcat

```
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hobak.sci/com.hobak.sci.Menu}: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { act=com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START }
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1961)
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1986)
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1152)
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4453)
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { act=com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START }
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1164)
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:370)
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277):     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.e(Unknown Source)
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277):     at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a(Unknown Source)
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277):     at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity$a.a(Unknown Source)
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277):     at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.initialize(Unknown Source)
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277):     at com.hobak.sci.Menu.onCreate(Menu.java:21)
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4467)
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1925)
03-17 15:55:51.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5277):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml? Most likely you are missing a permission there.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKQ8m27cfHg
Please check your device is available to play youtube.
in phone:  setting -> app -> youtube || setting to enable

Answer (score 10):

I was having this problem. Then I just added

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` into the `AndroidManifest.xml` in the `<manifest>` tag. The app worked fine after that.

Comment: hii i already add the permission for internet but still it gives me error same

Comment: @AndroidPower, make sure you clean your project and rebuild it. It happens that code changes in XML files do not automatically trigger Eclipse's autobuild feature.

Comment: hi now is play but if  youtube player app is not installed in mobile than is not play  i want to play youtubevideo without any other app how can i do this

Comment: @AndroidPower, I don't think can do that. If you read https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/, you'll notice: `Note: Users need to run version 4.2.16 of the mobile YouTube app (or higher) to use the API.`

Comment: Is this issue have any connection with debug mode and release mode? @alexismorin

Answer (score 5):

I've fixed this problem by doing steps below:

- Clean project then Rebuild Project
- Run the app in a device which has an Youtube app with a version higher than 4.2.16.

Answer (score 2):

maybe, it seems to developer key problem.
sample DEVELOPER_KEY key that located in DeveloperKey.java will be not work. 
first, register a new developer key. (https://code.google.com/apis/console)
then, replace this with a valid key.

Answer (score 2):

Just update your youtube app to the latest version in your phone and it will work perfect

Answer (score 1):

right click on project go to properties->java built in path->libraries->Add library and add your jar file there and then it's working

if you want to use youtube video in your application your device must have to contain an application of youtube otherwise it will not work

Comment: You saved my several hours. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue may also be caused by Android 11 restricting access to other apps. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility

Adding the following `<queries>` tag to `<manifest>` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` to declare that my app needs to access the Youtube package and matching the appropriate intent filter signature solved the issue for me:

```yaml
<manifest package="com.example.game">
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action
                android:name="com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
    ...
</manifest>
```

Read more: https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring#intent-filter-signature

Comment: Youtube apps can disable from samsung phones.. that case same error shown, what will do that case

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to the AndroidManifest.xml, you have to have the youtube app on the device/emulator.  If you want to get it on the emulator, sideload this:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.youtube&hl=en
(You can get the apk with http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/?id=com.google.android.youtube)

Answer (score 0):

**If the Player Fails on Google Glass**

When the youtube player fails, the YouTubeInitializationResult arg1 paramter passed to the failure method contains information about why the player failed. I simply toasted it, as you can see in the above code. I got a SERVIVE_MISSING print-out in the toast. I found the list of possible return values on [google's developer website](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeInitializationResult#getErrorDialog%28android.app.Activity,%20int%29), and the cause of the SERVICE_MISSING error is that the YouTube API service is missing on the device. This service is part of the standard youtube app that google distributes with android, but apparently has not added it to glass yet. To fix the problem, you can side-load the app to get the services. There is no way to launch the YouTube app and watch videos from it, unfortunately, since it was written for Android telephones and has no voice trigger/timeline card.

It can be downloaded from [here](http://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23189362627840301), or I have it loaded here: [com.google.android.youtube-5.2.27.apk](http://www.eg.bucknell.edu/~jpk017/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=wiki:com.google.android.youtube-5.2.27.apk)

Simply sideload this with:

`adb install com.google.android.youtube-5.2.27.apk`

This installs the youtube app on the glass. Now the video should work!

> taken from: http://www.eg.bucknell.edu/~jpk017/doku.php?id=wiki:yt

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on my release build but worked after adding this to proguard

```
-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
       public *;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after searching and googling so much , i got the answer that:-

```
           for youtube player you must have youtube app enabled and still if not work then update youtube to the latest version.
```

it would work then.